# RSS reader for iPhone with text-to-speech support?

Tags: iphone, applications, rss

I have been using gReader for Android for a long time. Now, I would like to switch to iPhone and I need a replacement for this app.

Is there any RSS reader for iPhone that converts text-to-speech?

Answer (score 1):

For RSS, I use [**Reeder 3**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/reeder-3/id697846300?mt=8&at=1001lwpF), but you can probably use your favourite app, because…

**iOS has built-in text-to-speech** support system-wide for selectable or unselectable text.

#### Method 1: Select text and speak it

Open Settings → General → Accessibility → Speech and enable Speak Selection.

> A Speak button will appear when you select text.

In an app like Reeder, hold down on the text, make a selection or choose Select All, then tap Speak.

[image]
[image]

#### Method 2: Speak all text

Open Settings → General → Accessibility → Speech and enable Speak Screen.

[image]
[image]

> Swipe down with two fingers form the top of the screen to hear the content of the screen.

A HUD appears for controlling speech, which hide automatically or with the left arrow and unhidden with the right arrow.

Comment: I'm looking for an app with built-in TTS option, like a music player, play/pause, forward and reverse options.