# Is there a good email app with text-to-speech for iPhone?

Tags: ios, email, software-recommendation, voice-dictation, text-to-speech

I cannot read small text due to eyesight deterioration and want an app that can read email out loud. Is there anything good that has text to speech and possibly also dictation of emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried Speaking Email ([speaking email website link](https://speaking.email)) and am finding it really great. It's a one by one email reader which keeps it nice and simple. It has commands like "delete", "reply" and so on which are voice commands, a nice idea - really powerful and no need to wear your eyes out peering at a screen.

The reply dictation works well. It is best for reasonably short emails. Although it works much better than Siri, which seemed to only get about half a sentence before thinking I am finished - whereas Speaking Email keeps the dictation going and only stops after something like 10 seconds, when you really are finished.

PS. I am answering my own question because I got this answer on Quora and thought I should share it here, since I found the app works great (my personal experience). Just in case anyone has the same question (hope that is the right thing to do here!)

Answer (score 1):

> Speak Screen
>
> From email to books, let your iPhone read to you. If you
> have a hard time reading the text on your iPhone, use Speak Screen to
> read your email, iMessages, web pages, and books. Turn on Speak Screen
> and swipe down from the top of the screen with two fingers, or just
> tell Siri to Speak Screen and have all the content on the page read
> back to you. You can adjust the voice’s dialect and speaking rate, and
> have words, sentences, or words within sentences highlighted as
> they’re being read. And the new Speech Controller provides a Speak
> Under Finger feature for more precise control.

https://www.apple.com/accessibility/iphone/vision/

From the Home screen, go to Settings → General → Accessibility → Speech → Speak Screen. Or simply search using the search bar in Settings. To read screen, imagine bringing down notification centre, but with two fingers.

For single words: select them, and find "Speak" in the tooltip options that appear.

[RSS reader for iPhone with text-to-speech support?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/335185/)

Comment: Thanks for this very nicely explained suggestion, this is ok but I was really more looking for an email app with support for text to speech. It is just quite fiddly to use the built in speak selection options